# asp.net access delete button of gridview

Tags: asp.net

How to access gridview commandfield delete button on RowDataBound event? 
How the cells and controls in griview are accessed

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
protected void YourGrid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Control button = e.Row.FindControl("btnSubmit");
    if (button != null && checkBox is Button)
    {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```

In `RowDataBound` event you may access row inner controls through `FindControl` method.

In the example above I assumed that you control is a `Button` control with `btnSubmit` identifier.

**Edit:** after the author's problem additional explanation:

```
(ButtonType)e.Row.Cells[commandFieldIndex].Controls[controlIndex];
```

`ButtonType` is the type of button being used by the `CommandField` - `Button`, `LinkButton`, or `ImageButton`. By default, the `CommandField` uses `LinkButtons`, but this can be customized via the CommandField’s `ButtonType` property.

Comment: lookin for commandfield button...not user delete button 
<asp:CommandField  ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowInsertButton="true"  />

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below. This is for adding a delete confirmation. But you can use it for anything you want.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
if (e.Row.Cells[1].HasControls())
{
LinkButton lnkbtnDelete = ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]);
lnkbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Do you want to Delete?');");
}
}
```

HTH